# Encoding String from Data as utf8 String does not equal expected value?

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

I am receiving a Data object in a function, and trying to convert it to a String. However, for some reason the value does not equal the expected value. Printing out the encoding String prints "en1" but comparing the String to "en1" results in false.

This is problematic for my Swagger API call, where I can submit a String but I cannot submit the encoded String. Is the payload variable below not a String, or is some weird encoding issue occurring? I also tried payload.stringValue and this did not work.

I really don't understand, thanks!

```
        ...
        let payload = String(data: record.payload, encoding: .utf8)

        self.data = payload

        print(payload) // prints "en1"
        print(payload == "en1") // returns false ?

        // query is to be of type String
        API.myCall(query: payload, completion: ...) // fails

        API.myCall(query: "en1", completion: ...) // succeeds
```

Comment: Inspect your string's code points, and see what you're getting: `Array("en1".utf8)`

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: ```let payload = String(data: record.payload, encoding: .utf8)``` returns optional. Make sure your are not sending ```"Optional("en1")"```to your API

Comment: print(Array("en1".utf8) == Array(payload.utf8)) returns false interestingly

Comment: ok got it, trying that thanks

Comment: `myCall(query:completion)` being? Also, could you give the output of `let hexPayload = record.payload.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined(); print(hexPayload)`?

Comment: @BrandonKalashian Take a look at the particular UTF8 code points that are in your strings, using the snippet I provided. Look up those UTF8 code points online and see what they actually are

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica if query parameter is a String it shouldn’t compile with an optional String

Comment: @Larme the output is `02656e31`

Comment: myCall(query:completion) is a SWAGGER Api POST call that takes in a String

Comment: I can confirm it is not an optional

Comment: So you are sending 4 bytes not 3

Comment: `"en1".data(using: .utf8).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()`, that' returns `656e31`, and you have `02656e31`. You see the diff? Your payload has `02` prefixing it. So when you compare, it's not the same, even if it looks like the same, invisible char?

Comment: any whitespaces maybe

Comment: Fascinating! So removing that invisible char should do the trick. I'm still learning Swift, thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem is the first byte. (02 means start of text)

Comment: It's not about removing that "invisible char" really, is why you are getting that byte `02`. Issue is on the `payload`, not on its "String conversion".

Comment: true, yes. Unfortunately, this is coming from a 3rd party library (an NFC reader).. my plan was to manually remove it for now, but report the issue.

Comment: It seems to be a NFCNDEFPayload .. I will look into this more closely. Thanks everyone